# How to output the input form data with extra model fields Django

Tags: ajax, django, django-forms, django-queryset

I'm looking for a way to output the input of a form (in a div) after the form has been submitted. After a lot of research, I can't find a solution. I think I need to use AJAX, but are not certain. Is there a proper Django way of getting this done, or do I need to work with AJAX?

something like this with AJAX?

```
  <script>
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open('GET', '???');
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      document.getElementById('ajax').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
    }
  };

  function sendAJAX() {
    xhr.send();
  }
  </script>
```

views.py

```
def scan_product_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.ScanProductForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            barcode_input = form.cleaned_data.get("barcode_input")
            amount_input = form.cleaned_data.get("amount_input")
            p = AddProduct.objects.get(barcode=barcode_input)
            p.sold = F("sold") + amount_input
            p.stock_amount = F("stock_amount") - amount_input
            p.save()
            messages.success(request, '%s was successfully scanned' %p.title)
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/scan/')
    else:
        form = forms.ScanProductForm()
    return render(request, 'scanapp/barscan.html', {'form': form})
```

template html

```
{% block content %}

<div class="scan-form-master">
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="scan-con">      
        <div>
            <div class="scan-form">
            {{ form }}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add">
            </div>
            <div class="conf-btn">  
                <div id="load" onclick="sendAJAX()">
                    <p>* I want to show the input of the above field input here after the client hit the Add button.</p>
                </div>
                <p><input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Print PDF">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="End session"></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there isn't an easy way to do this with django only. I would use jquery ajax to submit the form and then update a div with the response. There is some setup required to get your csrf token working with the ajax. [Django csrf ajax setup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request). Then use the JsonResponse instead of HttpResponseRedirect to send JSON to the front end.

Comment: Thanks! I'll going try to figure it out from here :-)